# Maven/IntelliJ import error: io.vertx.core does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, vert.x

I am trying to get the vertx library to compile in IntelliJ (w/ maven)

I had a lot of trouble getting maven to recognize/download the vertx dependency but I was able to resolve the dependency issues by downloading and installing the vertx libraries via the command line. Now I no longer have issues with the vertx dependencies and when I check the project dependencies in IntelliJ it has the correct path and shows no errors. 
The maven libraries in 'project structure' show up correctly and I've checked the directories for the .jar and .java files, they're all there.

I've also set my maven home directory to a fresh maven install:
C:/Program Files/apache-maven-3.3.3
and the settings file to the correct file:
C:\Users[User].m2\settings.xml
and the local repository (where maven has installed the requisite libraries)
C:\Users[User].m2\repository
These directories line up with libraries I've installed and the maven directories that seem to be working correctly (little red line that was there before I reinstalled the libraries and reset the caches is gone)

However, I am still not able to use the vertx libraries.

Also, this code is working on a friends mac, but I'm running windows and can't seem to get it to compile (java package does not exist error).

Comment: who does the compile? intellij or maven?

Comment: I'm trying to compile in intellij

Comment: well... question is too generic. the problem is likely not related to vertx. how about you start a new project using maven with dependency on a simple 3rd party library, and see if you can get everything working.

Comment: btw, if I may ask, what made you choose vertx?

Comment: I'm working on a team with other people and didn't make the decision myself, but we're building a REST API to handle requests from a couple different front end devices to an offsite server.

Comment: the problem certainly not vertex. maybe I should have just left that part out. IntelliJ says: "cannot resolve signal 'io' " in the line:
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;

Comment: This question is definitely _not_ too generic. IntelliJ can be bad about this, even in *nix. The problem is often that IntelliJ is using the wrong Java binary for the project, at least ime. I'm trying on my windows VM now.

Comment: ok, so it's simply IntelliJ config problem. Check File>Project Structure>Modules>Dependencies. If necessary, add each jar manually.

Comment: so I figured this out, see my answer below. it was a combination of maven configuration and a caching issue with intelliJ that was probably caused by the maven config problems. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took me forever, but I figured this out.

This was a caching issue and a problem with intelliJ not recognizing that I was importing a snapshot library with maven.

1: for some reason the settings.xml file that the vertx download website has does not have snapshots enabled, but (from what I understand) the most recent build of their system is a snapshot that maven updates from time to time. If snapshots are not enabled, maven intelliJ wont update/recognize the libraries. This was happening even though I had installed the libraries with mvn install.
settings.xml should look like:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>allow-snapshots</id>
      <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>snapshots-repo</id>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
          <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

2: After I fixed the above issue, I still had the same issue until I deleted the local cached libraries I had previously installed with maven (/user/.m2/repositories). For some reason intelliJ wouldn't recognize them. Once deleted, maven/intelliJ redownloaded them and then recognized them from that point on.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install the module with Maven by going to File - Project Structure - Add Libraries - Maven - and after googling the name of the module (it's `io.vertx:vertx-core` - io.vertx.core won't bring it up) I was able to install it fully using Maven and add it as a dependency from within IntelliJ. HTH.